# CSS 100% width not working after animation

Tags: css, width

Please visit website: http://viewlike.us/ and change resolution to e.g. 1920x1200 - in mostly cases header (div with input form and submit button ) is not anymore 100%. How to avoid this situation? Ive tried to use width:100% !important, min/max width - but without success. I suppose there should be a small trick/fix or sth to avoid it but Im struggling with lack of ideas.. thanks~!

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is. Seems to me like the submit button stays in the same place regardless of what I do.

Comment: @Victor: Just take a look http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/26078580.png its a piece of screen after using highest resolution.

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior after switching to the highest resolution, neither with Firefox 11 nor Google Chrome 18, on Linux. Which browser are you using? (By the way, you might want to add 1920x1080 as another resolution. I think that's more common than 1920x1200 to be honest. :)

Comment: @Victor: Thanks for reply :) It's curious because i'm using chrome and I've got such a issue. Interesting. Thanks for tip!

Comment: No problem. By the way, my screen resolution is 1920x1080 (you might have guessed that from my earlier suggestion :), maybe it only shows for people with 1920x1200 screen resolution?

Comment: @Victor: I reviewed css one more time. And it still happen. Im using 1280x800 res but problem still appears. I suppose this is kind of css bug which still need a fix.

Comment: Ah, I think I realize what is going on now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default value for the `width` property is `auto` for most elements. And in this case, the `<div>` is expanding to 100 percent of its parent element, which in your case is `<body>`. Since the `<body>` tag has no `width` defined, it will default to 100 percent of the browser window. So even though the width of the page located below the resolution selection bar is greater than the browser window's width, the top bars (URL entry and resolution selection) still have the width of the browser window. That is why you see the edge of them when you scroll to the right.

You might want to experiment with using `position: fixed` in combination with the CSS properties `top` and `left` for your top bars. That way, those bars will be on-screen even when you scroll the page to the right. (I tried that breefly and it should work.)

I hope that helps you!